# Creating an flutter app in vs code with firebase its showing the specific errors .Errors that showing is mentioned below and the signup widget code

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

'The name UserRecord isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument Try correcting the name to an existing type or defining a type named UserRecord

The method 'queryUserRecordOnce' isn't defined for the type '_SignupWidgetState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'queryUserRecordOnce'

The method 'createUserRecordData' isn't defined for the type '_SignupWidgetState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'createUserRecordData''

```
*import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'login.dart';
import 'package:easy_debounce/easy_debounce.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

import 'package:easy_debounce/easy_debounce.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class SignupWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignupWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignupWidgetState createState() => _SignupWidgetState();
}

class _SignupWidgetState extends State<SignupWidget> {
  TextEditingController emailTextController;
  TextEditingController textController1;
  TextEditingController textController2;
  TextEditingController passwordTextController;
  bool passwordVisibility;
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserRecord');
   final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    emailTextController = TextEditingController();
    textController1 = TextEditingController();
    textController2 = TextEditingController();
    passwordTextController = TextEditingController();
    passwordVisibility = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
          child: Align(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0.3, -0.8),
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 100, 0, 0),
                child: ListView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0.2, -0.35),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-0.55, -0.35),
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () async {
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                },
                                child: const FaIcon(
                                  FontAwesomeIcons.arrowLeft,
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(5, 4, 0, 5),
                                  size: 24,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Expanded(
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-2.5, -0.1),
                              child: Text(
                                'Signup',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Oswald',
                                  color: Color(0xFF0F5AA5),
                                  fontSize: 40,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Align(
                            alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0.05),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 250,
                              height: 400,
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [
                                    Color(0xFF0F5AA5),
                                    Color(0xFF0F5AA5),
                                  ],
                                  stops: [0, 0, 1],
                                  begin: AlignmentDirectional(0, -1),
                                  end: AlignmentDirectional(0, 1),
                                ),
                              ),
                              alignment: AlignmentDirectional(
                                  -0.09999999999999998, 0.5),
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-0.1, 1),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                          10, 15, 10, 0),
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        controller: emailTextController,
                                        onChanged: (_) => EasyDebounce.debounce(
                                          'emailTextController',
                                          Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                                          () => setState(() {}),
                                        ),
                                        autofocus: true,
                                        obscureText: false,
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          hintText: 'Mobile or Email',
                                          hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                            color: Color(0xFF000509),
                                          ),
                                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: Color(0xFF080F18),
                                              width: 1,
                                            ),
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                          ),
                                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: Color(0xFF080F18),
                                              width: 1,
                                            ),
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                          ),
                                          suffixIcon: emailTextController
                                                  .text.isNotEmpty
                                              ? InkWell(
                                                  onTap: () => setState(
                                                    () => emailTextController
                                                        ?.clear(),
                                                  ),
                                                  child: Icon(
                                                    Icons.clear,
                                                    color: Color(0xFF757575),
                                                    size: 22,
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                              : null,
                                        ),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                          color: Color(0xFF1A1F24),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                          10, 10, 10, 0),
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        controller: textController1,
                                        onChanged: (_) => EasyDebounce.debounce(
                                          'textController1',
                                          Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                                          () => setState(() {}),
                                        ),
                                        autofocus: true,
                                        obscureText: false,
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          hintText: 'Full name',
                                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                            color: Color(0xFF000509),
                                          ),
                                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: Color(0xFF080F18),
                                              width: 1,
                                            ),
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                          ),
                                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: Color(0xFF080F18),
                                              width: 1,
                                            ),
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                          ),
                                          suffixIcon: textController1
                                                  .text.isNotEmpty
                                              ? InkWell(
                                                  onTap: () => setState(
                                                    () => textController1
                                                        ?.clear(),
                                                  ),
                                                  child: Icon(
                                                    Icons.clear,
                                                    color: Color(0xFF757575),
                                                    size: 22,
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                              : null,
                                        ),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                          color: Color(0xFF1A1F24),
                                        ),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                          10, 10, 10, 0),
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        controller: textController2,
                                        onChanged: (_) => EasyDebounce.debounce(
                                          'textController2',
                                          Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                                          () => setState(() {}),
                                        ),
                                        autofocus: true,
                                        obscureText: false,
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          hintText: 'User name',
                                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                            color: Color(0xFF000509),
                                          ),
                                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: Color(0xFF080F18),
                                              width: 1,
                                            ),
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                          ),
                                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: Color(0xFF080F18),
                                              width: 1,
                                            ),
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                          ),
                                          suffixIcon: textController2
                                                  .text.isNotEmpty
                                              ? InkWell(
                                                  onTap: () => setState(
                                                    () => textController2
                                                        ?.clear(),
                                                  ),
                                                  child: Icon(
                                                    Icons.clear,
                                                    color: Color(0xFF757575),
                                                    size: 22,
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                              : null,
                                        ),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                          color: Color(0xFF1A1F24),
                                        ),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                          10, 10, 10, 25),
                                      child: FutureBuilder<List<UserRecord>>(
                                        future: queryUserRecordOnce(
                                          singleRecord: true,
                                        ),
                                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                          // Customize what your widget looks like when it's loading.
                                          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                            return const Center(
                                              child: SizedBox(
                                                width: 50,
                                                height: 50,
                                                child:
                                                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          }
                                          List<UserRecord>
                                              textFieldUserRecordList =
                                              snapshot.data;
                                          final textFieldUserRecord =
                                              textFieldUserRecordList.isNotEmpty
                                                  ? textFieldUserRecordList
                                                      .first
                                                  : null;
                                          return TextFormField(
                                            controller: passwordTextController,
                                            onChanged: (_) =>
                                                EasyDebounce.debounce(
                                              'passwordTextController',
                                              Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                                              () => setState(() {}),
                                            ),
                                            autofocus: true,
                                            obscureText: !passwordVisibility,
                                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                              hintText: 'Password',
                                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                                color: Color(0xFF000509),
                                              ),
                                              enabledBorder:
                                                  UnderlineInputBorder(
                                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                  color: Color(0xFF080F18),
                                                  width: 1,
                                                ),
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                              ),
                                              focusedBorder:
                                                  UnderlineInputBorder(
                                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                  color: Color(0xFF080F18),
                                                  width: 1,
                                                ),
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                              ),
                                              suffixIcon: InkWell(
                                                onTap: () => setState(
                                                  () => passwordVisibility =
                                                      !passwordVisibility,
                                                ),
                                                focusNode: FocusNode(
                                                    skipTraversal: true),
                                                child: Icon(
                                                  passwordVisibility
                                                      ? Icons
                                                          .visibility_outlined
                                                      : Icons
                                                          .visibility_off_outlined,
                                                  color: Color(0xFF757575),
                                                  size: 22,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                              color: Color(0xFF1A1F24),
                                            ),
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                          );
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                          0, 0, 0, 30),
                                      child: ElevatedButton(
                                        onPressed: () async {
                                          final user = await FirebaseAuth
                                              .instance
                                              .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                                  email:
                                                      emailTextController.text,
                                                  password:
                                                      passwordTextController
                                                          .text);

                                          if (user == null) {
                                            return;
                                          }

                                          final userCreateData =
                                              createUserRecordData(
                                            username: textController2.text,
                                            pass: passwordTextController.text,
                                            email: emailTextController.text,
                                            uid: textController1.text,
                                          );
                                          await UserRecord.collection
                                              .doc(user.uid)
                                              .update(userCreateData);

                                          await Navigator.push(
                                            context,
                                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) =>
                                                  LoginWidget(),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        },
                                        child: Text("signup"),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
 
}*
```

Comment: Please phrase your question properly

Comment: @Denzel help me with the errors